# Azure Data Factory - Copy Activity - Auto Create Table doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

ADF Copy Activity does not work when you select Auto Create Table in the Sink settings.
More specifically in my scenario I am using dynamic script to copy tables from the SQL Server ContosoRetailDW database to SQL Azure.
In cases where my source table has field like geometry or has a nvarchar field which contains brackets in the string then it fails.
Failed tables to date include DimCustomer, DimEmployee, DimGeography.
The same code works for most other tables.
Not sure this feature was tested before release.

Sample Code in Copy Activity:

Source Query:

```
SELECT * FROM  @{item().SourceSchema}.@{item().SourceObject}
```

Sink Settings:

```
Table Option: "Auto Create Table" is selected
Pre-Copy Script: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @{item().SinkSchema}.@{item().SinkObject}
```

Like I said this works for most tables when I run it but fails where tables have a geometry field or a nvarchar field string which has things like brackets in the string.
Summary of failed tables:

- DimCustomer - Field : Phone DataType: nvarchar(20) -- failing as there is a bracket in the string
- DimEmoloyee - Field : Phone DataType: nvarchar(25) -- failing as there is a bracket in the string
- DimGeography - Field: Geometry  DataType: Geometry  -- Failing in this data type

Will this feature be fixed in a near future release?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have seen this but the copy activity does not support all Data types . Please find the list mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping)

Comment: Thanks.  That's a small list and missing some highly used data types like char, varchar, nvarchar etc.   So are you saying as copy activity does not support these then don't expect auto create table to work.  Doesn't quite seem right to me. Especially considering I'm using Microsoft databases SQL Server and Azure SQL.

Comment: Sorry for replying on this very late . In your scenario the bracket in the name ( eg "(sometesttable" is s restriction on the SQL side if you 


CREATE TABLE (sometesttable
(
id int 
)   

errors out 



Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.